# $\int\cos(z)/(z⁵-32)dz$ on $|z|=2$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, curves, residue-calculus

> Evaluate $$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^5 -32} dz$$

I know that there is a singularity for $z=2$. And so, if $z_{0}=2$ is the singularity, I can apply the formula

$$\oint_{\gamma} f(z) dz=2\pi i \mathrm{Res}(f,z_{0})$$

We have that $g(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{z^4 +2z^3 +4z^2 +8z+16}$ is holomorphic and so have a Taylor series; $\frac{1}{z -2}$ is Laurent series with a simple pole with coefficient $1$

so $\mathrm{Res}(f,z_{0})=\frac{\cos(2)}{80}$ and we finally have that

$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{\cos(z)}{z^5 -32}dz=\pi i\frac{\cos(2)}{40}$$

Is it right?

Comment: $z^5 - 32$ has five roots, each of which is distinct and on the circle of radius $2$ (rather than inside of it). I think there is a lot more work to be done in justifying this...

Comment: The integral diverges, because you are integrating through the poles.  You could define the principal value in such a way that you encircle each pole with half a circle, and then take the limit as these circles go to zero radius.  In that case your result should be $\pi i \sum_{k=0}^4 \text{Res}(f,z_k)$.

Comment: @Evee, you are right. I have$ 2(cos(2kπ/5)+isin(2kπ)/5)$.